# Displaying Nested Object Keys and Values Within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the follow array:

```
var myArray = [
    {"cartItems": {"paramA1": 25, "paramA2": 35}},
    {"cartShippingCost": {"paramB1": 4, "paramB2": 152, "paramB3": 536, "paramB4": 56}},
    {"cartSpecialRequirements": {"paramC1": 432}},
    {"cartPostage": {"paramD1": 56, "paramD2": 6537}},
    {"uid": {"paramE1": 545}},
    {"tel": 7778798548}
];
```

I then group the above if 'cart' in the objects key:

```
var cartItems = myArray.filter(hasCartProperty);
var nonCartItems = myArray .filter(function (x) {
      return !hasCartProperty(x);
});


 function hasCartProperty(x) {
      return Object.keys(x).some(function (x) {
           return x.indexOf('cart') > -1;
      });
 }

 if(Object.keys(cartItems).length > 0) {
       cartItems.title = "Shopping Cart Items:";
 }
 if(Object.keys(nonCartItems).length > 0) {
       nonCartItems.title = "Non Cart Items:";
 }


 $scope.data = [cartItems, nonCartItems];
```

I then perform an ng-repeat:

```
<div x-ng-repeat="myItem in data">
    <p>{{myItem.title}}</p>
    <p x-ng-repeat="(key, value) in myItem">
        {{value}}
    </p>
 </div>
```

Which displays as:

```
Shopping Cart Items:
{"cartItems": {"paramA1": 25, "paramA2": 35}}
{"cartShippingCost": {"paramB1": 4, "paramB2": 152, "paramB3": 536, "paramB4": 56}}
{"cartSpecialRequirements": {"paramC1": 432}}
{"cartPostage": {"paramD1": 56, "paramD2": 6537}}


Non Cart Items:
{"uid": {"paramE1": 545}}
```

How can i display as:

```
Shopping Cart Items:

cartItems:
    {"paramA1": 25,
     "paramA2": 35}

cartShippingCost":
    {"paramB1": 4, "paramB2": 152,
     "paramB3": 536, "paramB4": 56}

cartSpecialRequirements:
    {"paramC1": 432}

cartPostage:
    {"paramD1": 56,
     "paramD2": 6537}


Non Cart Items:

uid:
    {"paramE1": 545}

tel:
    {7778798548}
```

Comment: In `var cartItems = o.filter(hasCartProperty);` o variable is myArray?

Comment: Correct, updated question

Answer (score 1):

Use pre tag and custom format function formatValue():

```
<div x-ng-repeat="myItem in data">
    <p>{{myItem.title}}</p>
    <pre x-ng-repeat="(key, value) in myItem">{{formatValue(value)}}</pre>
</div>
```

..

```
 $scope.formatValue = function(val) {
   var firstProp = Object.keys(val)[0];
   return firstProp + ":\r\n" + $filter("json")(val[firstProp]);
 };
```

Don't forget to add $filter to your controller dependences:

```
.controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope, $filter) {
```

Result:

[image]